# Jquery based on class get previous class number

Tags: jquery

I've this

```
<li class="sub_nivel nivel_3"> level 3 </li>
```

I need to on li over know the number of this "nivel_" in this case 3 so I can manipulate the previous nivel_2 z-index property.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the current number from the class value:

```
$("li.sub_nivel").on("click", function(){
    var nivel = $(this).attr("class").match(/nivel_([\d]+)/),
        antes = parseInt(nivel[1],10)-1 ;
    alert( antes );
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tHXyq/2/

Comment: Write `var antes=parseInt(nivel[1],10)-1 ;` in place of `antes=parseInt(nivel[1],10)-1 ;`. That is a good practice and will keep the scope of this variable inside the funuction.

Comment: @Imdad `antes` is declared with the same scope as `nivel`. Note the `,` at the end of the `nivel` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/8hrZw/1/

The sample HTML is

```
<ul>
 <li class="sub_nivel nivel_3"> level 3 </li>
 <li class="sub_nivel nivel_4"> level 4 </li>
 <li class="sub_nivel nivel_5"> level 5 </li>
</ul>
```

The jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li[class*='nivel_']").each(function(){
       var niv_num= $(this).attr("class").split("nivel_")[1];// get the number
        // You can do your z-index below instead of my code
        $(this).text("The number is "+niv_num);
    });
});
```

I'm changing the text according to the number.
You can do your code instead of changing the text.